# Scroll to Top when navigate to a new route in React using react-router v6.12

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having a problem when I'm going to another route, the scroll position stays on the same position as previous route.

I'm using `React` with `Vite` and `react-router v6.12` (latest version).

What i've tried: I've created a component that handles the `scrollToTop` and  I have imported and used in my `App.jsx` before the `<Outlet />` but it seems that it doesn't scroll to the top of the page (btw: the console.log message is printed).

When I've searched for this issues, many people solved their issue with below function, but for me it doesn't work.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollToTop = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        // first way..not working
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        // second way..still not working
        document.documentElement.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: "instant",
        });

        console.log("Called");
    }, [pathname]);

    return null;
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

My files are structured in this way:

main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "./router";

import "./App.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

router.js

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./views/layouts/App.jsx";

import HomePage from "./views/HomePage.jsx";
import Items from "./views/Items.jsx";
import About from "./views/About.jsx";
import Contact from "./views/Contact.jsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <App />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <HomePage />,
            },
            {
                path: "/items",
                element: <Items />,
            },
            {
                path: "/about",
                element: <About />,
            },
            {
                path: "/contact",
                element: <Contact />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);

export default router;
```

App.jsx

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

import ScrollToTop from "../../utilities/ScrollToTop";

import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <ScrollToTop />
            <Navbar />
            <div className="content">
                <Outlet />
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Bassically want I want to achive is this:

- When user navigate to a new page (cliks a < Link >) it must go to that page with scroll position to the top
- When pressing Back button (from browser Not clicking another < Link > that goes to previous page)  must go to the previous page on the same scroll position (if it is possible)

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy/Paste the code where you export the `scrollToTop` component file:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname]);

    return null;
}
```

Now in `App.js` file

```
function App(){
<>
<ScrollToTop />
<Routes>
<Route />
.
.
.
</Routes>
<>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Its working. Anyway, another problem was because I had the body with overflow-x-hidden and the #root with overflow-y-auto, so i just needed to remove the overflow